# Squidex issue, Run the Webpack Dev Server and no login page

Tags: content-management-system

I checkout Squidex from stash and try to run in my local. I am trying to run the Webpack Dev Server. I follow the instruction from official website without any change.

npm i (Install all dependencies for the frontend)
npm rebuild node-sass --force
npm run dev (Runs the webpack vdev server)

but when I open localhost:3000 from browser and tried to click Login to Squidex,
I got below error and then the popup login page disappeared.

oidc-client.min.js:1 Error parsing JSON response Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I have no idea what I can do to fix it. I do nothing change on it and just checkout source code and run in my local.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost:3000 is the webpack dev server. You have to run ASP.NET core app in VS2017 to start the Squidex app.

Ps. Don't forget to edit "baseUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx" in appsetting.json to match with your DEBUG url in Project > Properties.